# CoreData: Replacing Data Model with New Version?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, core-data

My app was originally published with a simple CoreData model.  The original source code was lost and has since been rebuilt with an entirely new CoreData model.

Everything seemed to be alright until you consider installations of the old app that would be upgraded.  I'm not entirely certain, but it appears that when installing the new version over the older one currently published on the App Store is problematic.  I'm not getting any specific error messages, but I can't think of any other reasons why the app would be quickly crashing.

Is there a relatively simple way to replace the previous version's data model with the new one?

Comment: I should ask this: do you have access to the provisioning profile used for the original app?  You need to use the same provisioning profile to update an app in the app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399).

You'll need to create a new "version" of your schema and then migrate to the new schema.

Comment: How can I do this when I do not have the original source code?

Comment: Without knowing the existing data model of the coredata store on the device, I don't think you'll be able to access that data to migrate it. You might be able to use introspection to reverse engineer your data fields, but that is going to take some work.

Comment: If you don't have the original data model source file, you're pretty much dead in the water.

Answer (score 0):

Do the migration yourself. Read the previos database during the initial run and copy everything to the new database. If you  jailbreak your device, you can access the file system using a file explorer and can copy the sqlite database file from the documents folder. You can find the coredata model by looking at the Sqlite tables(Ofcourse with a bit of trial and error).